# I cannot use rvm to install morden ruby in Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

I use RVM to install ruby 2.2.0,`rvm install 2.2.0 --disable-binary`
but I get the error:

```
  Error running 'requirements_debian_update_system ruby-2.2.0',

  showing last 15 lines of /home/gaoyikang/.rvm/log/1471531667_ruby-2.2.0/update_system.log
   ++ case "${TERM:-dumb}" in
   ++ case "$1" in
   ++ [[ -t 2 ]]
   ++ return 1
   ++ printf %b 'There has been error while updating '\''apt-get'\'',        please give it some time and try again later.
   404 errors should be fixed for rvm to proceed. Check your sources configured in:
/etc/apt/sources.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list\n'
There has been error while updating 'apt-get', please give it some time and try again later.
 404 errors should be fixed for rvm to proceed. Check your sources configured in:
/etc/apt/sources.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list

++ return 100
Requirements installation failed with status: 100.
```

I don't know how to fix it? Anyone hava faced the problem???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-software-properties libffi-dev
```

Then install latest version or required version of Ruby.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/549777/getting-404-not-found-errors-when-doing-sudo-apt-get-update